# Why typeof executed function return undefined

Tags: javascript

I've seen this in a JS test :

```
function aaa() {
   return
   {
       test: 1
   };
}
alert(typeof aaa());
```

Please explain me why the alert message is undefined ?
As I see it the should be object .

Comment: So I found the problem is return as line-break after it .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you returned nothing. Try this instead:

```
function aaa() {
   return {
       test: 1
   };
}
```

Now compare this with your code:

```
function aaa() {
   return 
   {
       test: 1
   };
}
```

Notice very carefully where I placed the opening `{`. It's on the same line as the return statement. In your example the opening `{` is on a new line which never executed because you have already returned nothing on the previous one.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment explaining why you think this answer is wrong.